# Error during Kubernetes Cluster creation

Tags: ibm-cloud, kubernetes, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to create a standard container cluster (Kubernetes) in Bluemix. When I do that, the masters appear to get ready, but worker provisioning fails with the following error:

> SoftLayer_Exception_Public: You do not have permission to verify
>   server orders. (HTTP 500)

I linked my Bluemix account to SoftLayer yesterday. Is there something else that I need to do before I can spawn a cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IBM/SoftLayer Support suggested to create an API Key for myself. To do that you go to `account > user > under API key > generate` after that i was able to spawn clusters using the bluemix ui

what also worked was to create a cluster with the bluemix CLI: `bx cs cluster-create --location fra02 --machine-type u1c.2x4 --workers 1 --name cliCluster`
For more documentation on this command see https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_cluster.html#cs_cluster_cli